# Is there any way to refresh FB/IG access token at website backend?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

We have an app which could login via Facebook or Instagram. And we will pull some basic information of the user's from the site if you do so. We want to update all those basic informations at a certain period of time by the backend. It's not necessary for us to update informations while the user is using the app. I think update the basic information is just a test. The company might want to give some useful recommendations to the client for some commercial reasons. Any way, I checked that Facebook access token will live for 60 days,Instagram access token will not expire for now. May I refresh access token at backend without user involved?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to refresh the User Token automatically (on the server), it needs user interaction. Else, it would be pointless to implement a 60 days limit.

Comment: Yeah I check it several times. They  just want it happen. How poor we are.

Comment: well, it´s a good thing. users who don´t use your app anymore should not be accessible. ;)

Comment: That's not cool. There should be business reasons for this. Despite all this, we're building a great app to help people do something. lol :D

Comment: The use case of "Our app" doing things automatically on behalf of the users at the expectation of the user is the issue. If the token expires, the app can no longer perform as the user expects - and we need to ask for them for action. This is fine if the tokens can be revoked, but don't expire (e.g. instagram token) - the user is still in control. If they do expire (e.g FB token) we need user action every 60 days :(